# Channel Form: Is there a bug with the control panel link included in emails?

Tags: safecracker, email, notification

Morning all,

I've developed a site on dev.domain.com and have since transferred to www.domain.com. I've updated all URL's in the new site to use www rather than dev but when someone completes the channel entry form on the site the notification email generated by EE (3.5.4) still shows a link to dev rather than www to view the new entry.

I've checked the control panel and all URL's look to be using www. I've also searched the database and can't see the dev domain anywhere.

Any ideas what could be going on would be massively appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Tom

Comment: I think that the values for the site preferences are stored in an encrypted array so searching the db directly will not find them.  Most likely you have missed a preference in the control panel (or in config.php).

Comment: Or perhaps in an email notification template?

Comment: I feel like a real idiot, it was hard-coded in an email notification template. It's the first EE3 site I've built after building lots on EE2 (well that's my excuse and I'm sticking to it). Thanks for your suggestion @AllInOne!